# MySQL Calculate average time between first initial received message and the first answer in one day

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have three table named `chats`, `chat_members`, and `chat_messages`. I want to get average time between first initial received message and the first answer in one day.

**chat_members**

```
|chat_id|user_id|
-----------------
|   1   |   3   |
|   1   |   4   |
|   2   |   3   |
|   2   |   6   |
```

**chat_messages**

```
|chat_id|sender_id|      body    |     created_at     |
------------------------------------------------------|
|   1   |   4     |"initial 1   "|2019-06-30 10:31:16 |
|   1   |   3     |"answer day 1"|2019-06-30 10:52:56 |
|   2   |   6     |"initial ans" |2019-06-30 10:54:33 |
|   2   |   3     |"answer"      |2019-06-30 10:56:30 |
|   1   |   4     |"initial 2"   |2019-07-01 09:30:02 |
|   1   |   3     |"answer day 2"|2019-07-01 09:45:02 |
```

Expected results: Average response time for spesific user. Let's say `user_id: 3` have average response time `17.5 minutes`.

```
|chat_id|avg_minutes|
--------------------|
|   1   |   20      |
|   2   |   15      |
```

Think it as a facebook page average response time:

> “Response time is the average time it takes your Page to send initial responses to new messages in one day.”

Comment: Could you add a table to your expected results?

Comment: Based on your data, the resposnetime of `sender_id` = 3 is (20+15)/2 = 17.5 minutes, not 30. Do you want a PHP or MySQL solution? What efforts have you made so far?

Comment: I am sorry, it's just sample data. I don't calculate it manually before asking this question.
I made something like:
`SELECT chat_id FROM members GROUP BY chat_id WHERE sender_id='{$user}'

SELECT AVG(response) FROM (
    SELECT  WHERE chat_id=chat_id AND sender_id <> $sender_id GROUP BY DAY(created_at) 
    WHERE IN chat_id=($chat_id)
)`

I think it's my limit, so i asking this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an intermediate answer...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS chat_messages;
CREATE TABLE chat_messages
(message_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,chat_id INT NOT NULL
,sender_id INT NOT NULL
,body VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
,created_at DATETIME NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO chat_messages VALUES
(1,1,4,'initial 1','2019-06-30 10:31:16'),
(2,1,3,'answer day 1','2019-06-30 10:52:56'),
(3,2,6,'initial ans','2019-06-30 10:54:33'),
(4,2,3,'answer','2019-06-30 10:56:30'),
(5,1,4,'initial 2','019-07-01 09:30:02'),
(6,1,3,'answer day 2','2019-07-01 09:45:02');

SELECT x.*
     , y.sender_id responder
     , MIN(y.created_at) response 
  FROM chat_messages x 
  JOIN chat_messages y 
    ON y.chat_id = x.chat_id 
   AND y.created_at > x.created_at 
   AND y.sender_id <> x.sender_id 
 GROUP 
    BY x.message_id,y.sender_id;
+------------+---------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+
| message_id | chat_id | sender_id | body        | created_at          | responder | response            |
+------------+---------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+
|          1 |       1 |         4 | initial 1   | 2019-06-30 10:31:16 |         3 | 2019-06-30 10:52:56 |
|          3 |       2 |         6 | initial ans | 2019-06-30 10:54:33 |         3 | 2019-06-30 10:56:30 |
|          5 |       1 |         4 | initial 2   | 0019-07-01 09:30:02 |         3 | 2019-06-30 10:52:56 |
+------------+---------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+
```

This gives us the time of each responder's earliest response.

Next, we can aggregate the difference between created_at and response, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: thank you. i am going to try it. it seems like this can answer my problem.